# Participle as adjective

Tags: grammatical-case

I have learned that one uses the Partizip I when the action is not yet completed or in an active sentence and the Partizip II if the action is completed or in a passive sentence.

But this sentence confuses me:

> Das vor einer Einfahrt parkende Auto

To me that sounds as if the car is in the process of parking in front of an entrance. But my German friends say it is already parked.

If it was already parked, I would use the Partizip II like this:

> Das vor einer Einfahrt geparkte Auto

Do both sentences really mean the same thing?

Comment: "Ban on cars parking on pavements could soon be brought in" (gazette-news, .uk) this shows that you have to be more subtle about "in the process of" in English too.

Comment: The trick is to search for "cars parking", plural and with qoutes, otherwise you get the more commeon usages. Why you stop your example sentence in the middle? Very artificial!

Comment: "I am seeing more and more cars parking on sidewalks and curbs." This is L.A.. USA. Different names, different pictures (a LA curb is not a UK pavement:-), same grammar/semantics, as in German

Answer (score 7):

*Parken* is definitely the wrong verb to learn about this contrast. It can be used both transitively and intransitively. In the transitive case, it signifies an action (*abstellen*).

> (1) Geschickt parkte sie den Wagen. *(transitive, action)*

In the intransitive case, the subject can either be the owner or the vehicle. The meaning is similar to *stehen*, signifying a state.

> (2) Ich hab's eilig, ich parke in der zweiten Reihe. *(intransitive, state)*
>
> (3) Das Auto parkte noch dort, wo er es abgestellt hatte. *(intransitive, state)*

Intransitive + state with present participle, similar to (2):

> (4) Ein 61-jähriger Mann aus Isernhagen muss wegen eines abgelaufenen Parkscheins eine höhere Strafe zahlen als **seine hinter ihm parkende Frau**, die gar keinen Parkschein hatte.

Transitive + action with present participle, similar to (1):

> (5) **selbstparkende Autos**

These are cars that park themselves, or are able to do so. The *selbst* allows for the interpretation as an action. *Parkende Autos* by itself would be interpreted as a state, similar to (3).

The past participle of *haben* verbs always refers to the object. Therefore, the following example is similar to transitive *parken* in (1) and stands for the result of the completed action.

> das dort geparkte Auto
> = das dort abgestellte Auto
> = das Auto, das jemand dort abgestellt hat

This is indeed synonymous to the analogue of (3), intransitive *parken*:

> das dort parkende Auto
> = das dort stehende Auto
> = das Auto, das dort steht

Comment: +1 from me... Transitive and intransitive of course is the right direction to go here...

Comment: Great analysis.-- As an aside, I just found it very funny to understand "selbstparkendes Auto"  in the intransitive sense -- see, it's standing there all by itself, imagine! What a technological breakthrough!

Comment: On a more serious side, "das Auto parkt selbst -- es ist ein selbstparkendes Auto" is a hybrid: it is clearly not meant in the classical intransitive sense, because that would be the joke I mentioned. It should be reflexive: "Das Auto parkt *sich* selbst, es ist ein sich selbst parkendes Auto"! Like "ein selbstklebender Haken"  is one which sticks to the wall ("klebt an der Wand", intransitive) on its own; it is not a hook which jumps up and glues itself to the wall, an invention which could be dubbed "der *sich* selbst klebende Haken". For now we transitively "kleben den Haken an die Wand".

Answer (score 4):

You mix up two meanings of the verb „parken“ in German.

The first meaning -the one you asume in your example sentence- is the process of parking a car. An example would be:

> Der Fahrer parkt das Auto auf dem Parkplatz

The second meaning is the action that the car itself does: it‘s standing on a parking lot. The example would be:

> Das Auto parkt auf dem Parkplatz

When using the first meaning then the Partizip „parkend“ would indeed mean the process of parking, but this is highly uncommon. Here a German would rather use the verb „einparken“ to show the process:

> Das einparkende Auto rammte den Baum

Or

> Der einparkende Fahrer rammte (mit dem Auto) den Baum.

Whenever you use the Partizip of „parken“ most Germans will understand this as „standing still“ as in:

> Das parkende Auto

„Geparkt“ of course would be right in any case, as it doesn‘t matter, which of the meanings was originally meant as the result is always a car standing on a parking lot...

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Anything I can improve? Or is this another „revenge“- downvote of a user known for doing this?

Comment: i downvoted the rest, at least you keep it simple, and mention einparken, which would help if somebodey was interested.

Comment: no: Don't downvote good answers... just downvote bad answers... You can even upvote multiple answers... downvoting is only to show, that you disagree with an answer, not to show that another one is better (in your opinion)... and the other answer is definitively good!